# Error Migrating CRM 4.0 to CRM 2011

Tags: migration, crm, microsoft-dynamics-crm

I have a CRM 4.0 32bit in my network with SQL 2008 SP3 installed on it.

I installed a new CRM 2011 64bit server with SQL 2008 R2 SP1 on my network with reports extension and update rollup 5.

On the 4.0 server, I created a backup of the CRM organization database (just that, didn't take the MSCRM_CONFIG) and restored it to the 2011 server.

Using the deployment manager, I disabled the already existing organization that comes with CRM 2011, and tried to import the restored 4.0 database, the import process took around 30 minute and the notification bar went all to the end, it failed with this error:

```
17:55:00| Info| Setting organization state. New state = Failed 
17:55:00| Error| Upgrade Organization with Id=00df99ad-612d-4d30-80dc-40cb2aa60934 failed with Exception:
 System.Exception: Action Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.UpgradeNewSolutionAwareEntities failed. ---> Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: There should only be one role for a role template in root business. TemplateId d9d602db-2761-4170-877f-983494567c08
 at Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.SolutionsUpgrade.RoleSolutionUpgrader.GetRoleForTemplate(Guid templateId, ExecutionContext context)
 at Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.SolutionsUpgrade.RoleSolutionUpgrader.Upgrade(ExecutionContext context)
 at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.UpgradeNewSolutionAwareEntities.Do(IDictionary parameters)
 at Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Common.CrmAction.ExecuteAction(CrmAction action, IDictionary parameters, Boolean undo)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Can anyone please help me with this error?

Comment: As this is a problem with dynamics not Windows or SQL I've swapped out the tags so you hopefully get the right people looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that one of the developers used to have access to the DB installation of CRM and used to play with the tables in there, there was a duplicate entry for one of the security rules in the CRM, deleting that entry from the database we were able to continue with the migration process.